# Textview of another page change on button click in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have got 2 relative layouts in a page and when i click on these 2 layouts it goes into same page with heading Enquiry form. Now i want to change the heading which means that when i click on one layout it should goes to same page enquiry form but with different heading and when i click on other layout it should goes to same page with another heading in android studio using intent

Comment: Put your efforts here so someone can help you in better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do using putExtra ( SendingActivity )

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
i.putExtra("TITLE", headingTitle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get intent Second Activity ( RecievingActivity )

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TITLE");
textview.setText(data);
```

pass title in putExtra and SecondActivity you can get Intent and set title in textview

Comment: what is 'headingTitle' in first activity?, I had given the id as title in second activity

Comment: so what should i write inside semicolon ("TITLE")

Comment: its a Key , you need both side same key so you can send and receive data. so here do not change this.